# Characters and Access level of inherated constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

From a book I am referring, I found something like:

> Unlike using declarations for ordinary members, a constructor using
> declaration does not change the access level of the inherited
> constructor(s). For example, regardless of where the using declaration
> appears, a private constructor in the base is a private constructor in
> the derived; similarly for protected and public constructors.

But I am finding difficulties understanding it. Can anyone elaborate it. How can even a private constructor be accessed from Base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following code,

```
class B {
protected:
    B(int) {}
};

class D : public B {
public:
    using B::B;
};
```

then

```
D d(0); // error: calling a protected constructor of class 'B'
```

Even the accessibility of [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) `using B::B` is `public`, `B::B(int)` is still `protected` and not accessible. It's the same if `B::B(int)` is `private`, except for it can't be accessed from derived class either.

(emphasis mine)

> If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, **it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored**.

On the other hand, it's different with other members, e.g.

```
class B {
protected:
    void f(int) {}
};

class D : public B {
public:
    using B::f;
};
```

then

```
D d;
d.f(42); // fine. D::f is public
```

Comment: It means that private constructor can't be accessed from none of derived class?

Comment: @Dev-il Yes, that's what `private` means; it could be accessed only by the class itself or its friends.

Answer (score 0):

> How can even a private constructor be accessed from Base class.

It can't, unless there's `friend`ship involved.

So, yes, that's a bad example.

It should have gone with `protected` instead to avoid confusion.